# Role of space while sorting words

Tags: python, string, sorting

I was playing through a python code to sort the words alphabetically. I realized when I write "," and ", " the output changes. This might be basic but can anyone help me understand why this happens?

1st case:

My code:

```
string = input("enter comma separated sequence of words: ").split(",")
string = sorted(string)
print(','.join(string))
```

**Output:** enter comma-separated sequence of words: red, white, black, red, green, black

**Sorted:**  black, black, green, red, white,red

2nd case:

My code:

```
string = input("enter comma separated sequence of words: ").split(", ")
string = sorted(string)`enter code here`
print(', '.join(string))
```

**Output:** enter comma separated sequence of words: red, white, black, red, green, black

**Sorted**: black, black, green, red, red, white

Comment: If you look closely, it appears that you might be missing some spaces in your first CSV input.  This looks like a typo to me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it looks like there are spaces causing the issue.

```
string = input("enter comma separated sequence of words: ").split(",")

string = sorted(string, key=lambda x : x.strip())
print(','.join(string))
```

Comment: You could also trim whitespace after splitting, and then join with a comma and space, like:
`input("whatever").split(",").trim()`

Then it would be `string.sort()`, 

and `print(', ').join(string)`

Comment: @Dash dont think this works, because ``trim()`` is a string function & ``split`` would return list.

Comment: @Susanth you're right, I totally forgot. I guess you could do `[s.strip() for s in string.split()]` instead

Comment: I have yet to learn lambda function but thanks for the answer @Sushanth

Answer (score 0):

you only need to split the words by the space between the words.
Try this:

```
my_string = input("enter words here: ")
result = [x.strip() for x in my_string.split(',')]
print (','.join(sorted(result)))
```

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: This did help. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

When you split on only the comma (`","`) the space that trails the comma is retained as the first character of the word following the comma.

The first word in the list, `red`, does not have a leading space.  When collating, a space character sorts ahead of any letter.  All the color names appear first as sorted with the leading space and are followed by the `red` that has no leading space.

Perhaps this will help illustrate:

```
>>> string = input("enter comma-separated sequence of words: ").split(",")
enter comma-separated sequence of words: red, white, black, red, green, black
>>> string = sorted(string)
>>> for s in string:
...     print(f"[{s}]")
...
[ black]
[ black]
[ green]
[ red]
[ white]
[red]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers are good. I have just added a case where user might enter empty spaces between commas...like A,Z, ,C.
The following code covers this case too.

```
words = input("enter comma separated words here: ")
wordsList= [x.strip() for x in my_string.split(',') if x.strip() !=""]
sortedWords = ','.join(sorted(result))

return sortedWords
```